# Scaling a Bitmap Efficiency

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I am wondering which one of this two ways is more efficient in terms of memory or speed.

### FIRST WAY - `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`

```
    Bitmap loadedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.big_image);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = loadedBitmap.createScaledBitmap(loadedBitmap, 1920, 1080, false);
```

### SECOND WAY - `(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable()`

```
    Bitmap loadedBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.big_image)).getBitmap();
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = loadedBitmap.createScaledBitmap(loadedBitmap, 1920, 1080, false);
```

Comment: You can implement for both to compare on each way. I usually use second way to load bitmap from resource.

Answer (score 1):

First Way is better.

```
 Bitmap loadedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.big_image);
 Bitmap scaledBitmap = loadedBitmap.createScaledBitmap(loadedBitmap, 1920, 1080, false);
```

Comment: Yes in second cade GetDrawable first create Drawable object and than from that  it create a bitmap in first case it directly converts the drawabbe to bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically  first way is much better.
The reason is,

```
Bitmap loadedBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.big_image)).getBitmap();
```

You are attempting explicit conversion when it comes to ,

```
((BitmapDrawable)<drawable object>
```

Here BitmapDrawable is a sub class of Drawable, then Its a Downcasting which is more tend to fail and throw ClassCastException.